# How do I access and setState() of a parent component, from a child component onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, dom

I'm a young dev trying to learn some `Reactjs`, but I'm having trouble understanding how to configure this Todo app. My goal is to have a button that will add items to the list once entered and submitted. I feel like I'm pretty close to having it figured out.
I've got an App component (parent), button component, and a List component(also a header and item component). the list has a variable that has an empty array for me to add items to, which I reference in my App component.
Here lies the problem. I have an event listener on my button that runs a function that sets the state. I'm logging the list every time I click, which shows that the array is receiving the text inputs and making a new object. However, **the DOM is not re-rendering** what confuses me even more, is that when I make a slight edit (random semicolon) the DOM renders the items that were entered and logged before I last saved, but remains unresponsive.
What am I missing here? Also, I understand that lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount()` or `componentDidUpdate()` may be useful, but I do not fully understand how and where to use them.

```
export class Button extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}

handleClick() {
    const text = document.getElementById('text_field');
    const input = text.value;
    
        this.setState(() => {
            TodoList.push({id: (TodoList.length+1), name: input})
        })
    console.log(TodoList)
}

render() { 
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='search-container'>
                <input className='search' type='text' placeholder='type something...' id='text_field'></input>
            </div>
            <div className='button-container'>
                <button type='submit' className='button-add' onClick={this.handleClick}> New Task </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        todos: TodoList
    }
}

render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
        console.log(todo.name, todo.id);
        return <Item desc={todo.name} key={todo.id} /> 
    })
    
    return(
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <div className='card'>
                <Header numTodos={this.state.todos.length}/>
                <div className='todo-list'>
                    {todoItems}
                </div>
                <Button />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}
export default App

Comment: You have to send setState as props of child, and then in child use onClick which will call this props, which you are sending

Comment: What I would recommend is looking into using Redux since it is pretty much the standard state management library for React these days. Learning how to use "actions" will make some of this stuff much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.js, you should pass a function to `<Button />`, this technique called `function as prop` in react. The `App.js` code should look like below:

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        todos: TodoList
    }
}

addTodo = (todo) => {
  this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos, todo] })
}

render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
        console.log(todo.name, todo.id);
        return <Item desc={todo.name} key={todo.id} /> 
    })
    
    return(
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <div className='card'>
                <Header numTodos={this.state.todos.length}/>
                <div className='todo-list'>
                    {todoItems}
                </div>
                <Button todosList={this.state.todos} addTodo={(todo) => this.addTodo(todo)} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

In the code for `Button.js`, you get this function via `this.props`

```
export default class Button extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}

handleClick() {
    const text = document.getElementById('text_field');
    const input = text.value;
    this.props.addTodo({id: this.props.todosList.length + 1, name: input })
    console.log(this.props.todosList)
}

render() { 
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='search-container'>
                <input className='search' type='text' placeholder='type something...' id='text_field'></input>
            </div>
            <div className='button-container'>
                <button type='submit' className='button-add' onClick={this.handleClick}> New Task </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```